# Using interrupts with W65C02 and W65C22

Tags: circuit-design, interrupts, cpu

I’m trying to use the interrupts of the 6502 and 6522. I want to read the value of PORTA whenever the “READY” line I have is HIGH.

I think I understood that I have to put the “READY” line on CA1 and that it’ll output some stuff to IRQ when it’s HIGH. Then, in the code, I created a pointer to my interrupt “function” at address fffe and it should execute that code when the “READY” line is HIGH. But it’s not working.

I saw stuff about Interrupt Enable and Flag, but don’t understand how it should work. So if you could explain what I need to do for it to execute code whenever a CA1 is HIGH, it would help me a lot!

I made this project based on Ben Eater's 6502 project and I'm trying to add support for a PS/2 keyboard.

Here's a schematic of the circuit:
[image: Only the 6502 and 6522 are shown all the rest is same as Ben Eater]
I have another 6522 for the LCD screen, the LCD's 6522 is at adress 6000 and the Keyboard's 6522 is at adress 4000.

And you can find the Assembly code at this link:
[keyboard.s](https://sigmaserv.fr/6502/keyboard.s)

Comment: That's awfully vague. Can you add a diagram showing how you have the hardware wired up, and also the source code for what you're running on the CPU?

Comment: `it’s not working` is a useless description of a problem, any problem ... a clear description of what you observed may help identify the area of failure

Comment: Sorry I was to vague, I updated the post explaining it properly (I hope). Thank you